# give overlay different ids from foreach

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, foreach

I have a foreach fetched by firestore, each document has a button classed
"update Sets" this is connected to an overview with has more information to edit. I tried to make each overview have different ids by giving an id from firestore in place of the id="" part but I'm not sure how to make the overview know what document is clicked on

```
const Session = document.getElementById("session");

const roundRef = collection(db, "uuid", uid, "programme", id, "exercises");
const roundOrder = query(roundRef, orderBy("order"));

const roundsUnsub = onSnapshot(roundOrder, (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        const DocId = doc.id;
        const data = doc.data()
        const exerciseID = doc.data()

        console.log(data)

        //need to remove the arrow clickers on the number input , but to only she the numbers on the keyboard ehrb its clicked

        Session.innerHTML += `
        
            <div class="sets-list">
                <div class="exercise-name">${data.name}</div>
                <div class="update-button" id="${exerciseID}">Update Sets</div>
            </div> 
            
            <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-content">
                    <div class="overlay-tab"></div>
                    <div class="exercise-set-name">${data.name}</div>

                    <div class="set-row">
                        <div class="set">Set 1</div>
                        <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" id="${data.exerciseID}oneReps" type="text" placeholder="${data.oneReps}"></input>
                        <div class="weight">Weight</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" type="number" placeholder="${data.oneWeight}"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="set-row">
                        <div class="set">Set 2</div>
                        <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" id="reps" type="number" placeholder="${data.twoReps}"></input>
                        <div class="weight">Weight</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" type="number" placeholder="${data.twoWeight}"></input>
                    </div>
              
                    <div class="set-row">
                        <div class="set">Set 3</div>
                        <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" id="reps" type="number" placeholder="${data.threeReps}"></input>
                        <div class="weight">Weight</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" type="number" placeholder="${data.threeWeight}"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="set-row">
                        <div class="set">Set 4</div>
                        <div class="reps">Reps</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" id="reps" type="number" placeholder="${data.fourReps}"></input>
                        <div class="weight">Weight</div>
                        <input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="exercise-input" type="number" placeholder="${data.fourWeight}"></input>
                    </div>

                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closeNav">
                        <div class="exercise-save-button">Save Set</div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>`

        document.getElementById(exerciseID).addEventListener("click", function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "60%";
        });

        document.getElementById("closeNav").addEventListener("click", function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is the problem that you can't get the `id` to work in the `forEach` loop, or that you don't know what to do with the button now that it has a unique ID?

Comment: I thought that as its showing multiple documents from a collection and i have given them their own id that it would attach that to the overlay. But the overlay only works on the first document (and doesn't show if you click the other buttons) and only shows that data of that first document

Comment: OK there isn't enough information to troubleshoot that here (how does that mechanism work? There are no `onClick` events in the code you have shared here). Also I would suggest updating your question and title, as neither are very clear about what your problem is and what you expect it to do.